# SQL RECURSIVE TABLE INFINITE LOOP

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have a table of companies, with three columns: holder_co_id, held_co_id, pct_owned.

```
holder_co_id  held_co_id  pct_owned
A             B           25
A             C           50
B             C           50
C             B           10
```

So my query identifies that A holds 25% of B, A holds 50% of C and A holds a further 5% of B through it's 50% holding in C and a further 12.5% of C through the holding in B.

I was super super happy with myself as for once I'd nailed some sql. This did not last long. I noticed that with the mutual ownership of B and C, this sends the query into an infinite loop. I have tried stopping the loop by putting a max on the loops, but this gives ownerships in some cases still above 100%... besides, it's just not correct.

Any ideas on how else I would do this other than:

```
WITH Result AS 
(SELECT HOLDER_CO_ID, 
        HELD_CO_ID, 
        PCT_OWNED, 
        1 AS generationsremoved
FROM dbo.ALL_HOLDING_INFO
UNION ALL
SELECT  P.HOLDER_CO_ID, 
        N.HELD_CO_ID, 
        P.PCT_OWNED * N.PCT_OWNED AS Expr1,
        P.generationsremoved + 1 AS Expr2
FROM  Result AS P INNER JOIN
dbo.ALL_HOLDING_INFO AS N ON P.HELD_CO_ID = N.HOLDER_CO_ID
WHERE     (P.generationsremoved <= 10))
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT HOLDER_CO_ID, 
                                  HELD_CO_ID, 
                                  PCT_OWNED, 
                                  generationsremoved
 FROM         Result AS Result_1
 WHERE     (PCT_OWNED > 0.005)
 ORDER BY HOLDER_CO_ID, HELD_CO_ID, generationsremoved DESC
```

Comment: Pretty sure the way to fix this... would be to remove the infinite loop.

Comment: Given all that, what's the right answer?

Comment: It's perfectly possible (although probably not _legal_) to have percentages greater than %100 (a la The Producers).  Are you sure there's a viable "minimum percentage owned"?  You may need to at least be able to effectively record percentages equivalent to 1 share (and there are probably some real-world situations that result in _fractions of a share_...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try stopping your `iteration` on the `Recursive block` of your CTE instead of doing it outside, my guess is if you stop it while SQL is trying to build it (inside the recursive block) it wont get into a infinite loop

```
  WITH Result AS 
    (SELECT HOLDER_CO_ID, 
            HELD_CO_ID, 
            PCT_OWNED, 
            1 AS generationsremoved
    FROM dbo.ALL_HOLDING_INFO
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  P.HOLDER_CO_ID, 
            N.HELD_CO_ID, 
            P.PCT_OWNED * N.PCT_OWNED AS Expr1,
            P.generationsremoved + 1 AS Expr2
    FROM  Result AS P INNER JOIN
    dbo.ALL_HOLDING_INFO AS N ON P.HELD_CO_ID = N.HOLDER_CO_ID
    WHERE     (P.generationsremoved<= 10)
      AND (PCT_OWNED > 0.005))
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT HOLDER_CO_ID, 
                                      HELD_CO_ID, 
                                      PCT_OWNED, 
                                      generationsremoved
     FROM         Result AS Result_1
```

Comment: The `PCT_OWNED` that is limiting to greater than 0.005 is ambiguous. Can you alias it with the desired table?

Comment: I don't think this accomplishes the real world goal the OP is going for as this will still continue the loop depth that is undesired and return irrelevant data. If C owns 50% of B and B own 50% of C then they both own 50% of eachother they don't own 50% + 25% + 12.5% + 6.25% + ... of eachother.

Comment: Love2Learn's correct, have tried this and I get the same infinite loop. I should not have included "AND (PCT_OWNED > 0.005)" in the code posted, just another route I had tried and forgot to take out for post. Soz.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you what you want. It first creates a hierarchy and then iterates through it and finally sums the aggregates to get you the total holding. As long as neither the HOLDER_CO_ID or HELD_CO_ID have a `|` in them this will work...

```
/*
If      Object_ID('dbo.ALL_HOLDING_INFO') Is Not Null Drop Table dbo.ALL_HOLDING_INFO
Create  Table dbo.ALL_HOLDING_INFO (HOLDER_CO_ID Varchar(10), HELD_CO_ID Varchar(10), PCT_OWNED Float)

Insert  dbo.ALL_HOLDING_INFO
Values ('A', 'B', .25),('A', 'C', .50),('B' ,'C', .50),('C','B',.10);
*/


With    Hierarchy As
(
        Select  Distinct HOLDER_CO_ID As HOLDER_CO_ID, 
                HELD_CO_ID As HELD_CO_ID,
                PCT_OWNED,
                Convert(Varchar(Max),'|' + HELD_CO_ID + '|') As AllChildren, 
                0 As RelationDepth
        From    dbo.ALL_HOLDING_INFO
        Union   All
        Select  h.HOLDER_CO_ID, 
                a.HELD_CO_ID As HELD_CO_ID,
                a.PCT_OWNED,
                Convert(Varchar(Max),h.AllChildren + a.HELD_CO_ID) + '|' As AllChildren, 
                h.RelationDepth + 1
        From    Hierarchy h
        Join    dbo.ALL_HOLDING_INFO a
                On  h.HELD_CO_ID = a.HOLDER_CO_ID
        Where   h.HOLDER_CO_ID != a.HELD_CO_ID
        And     h.AllChildren Not Like '%|' + a.HELD_CO_ID + '|%'
), Result AS 
(
        SELECT  Row_Number() Over (Order By Holder_CO_ID, PCT_OWNED) As tID,
                HOLDER_CO_ID, 
                HELD_CO_ID, 
                PCT_OWNED, 
                RelationDepth
        FROM    Hierarchy
        Where   RelationDepth = 0
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT  p.tID,
                P.HOLDER_CO_ID, 
                N.HELD_CO_ID, 
                P.PCT_OWNED * N.PCT_OWNED AS Expr1,
                n.RelationDepth
        FROM    Result AS P 
        JOIN    Hierarchy AS N 
                ON  P.HOLDER_CO_ID = N.HOLDER_CO_ID
                And p.HELD_CO_ID != n.HELD_CO_ID
                And p.RelationDepth = n.RelationDepth - 1
)
SELECT  HOLDER_CO_ID, HELD_CO_ID, SUM(PCT_OWNED)*100 As PCT_OWNED                             
FROM    Result AS Result_1
Group   By HOLDER_CO_ID, HELD_CO_ID
ORDER   BY HOLDER_CO_ID, HELD_CO_ID DESC
```

Comment: PS: If you want the individual chunks simply take out the aggregation logic in the final select at the bottom.

Comment: OOOOO so close! I thought the above was perfect til I noticed that company C is owned 112.5% in total :-) I'll take a closer look, see if I made a mistake. building a hierarchy first - this is definitely the way to go, thx Love2learn